# Why my compressed output using GZIPOutputStream is not matching when we decompressed the same string using any online compression tools

Tags: java, compression, gzipoutputstream

I am using below code to compress my test string into gzip format

'private static final String TEST_STRING = "Test String";

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Original data: " + TEST_STRING);
    String compressedString = compress(TEST_STRING);
    System.out.println("Compressed data: " + compressedString);
}


private static String compress(String str){
    byte[] byteArray = str.getBytes();
    final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (GZIPOutputStream gzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream)) {
        gzipOutputStream.write(byteArray);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occurred during compressing" + e);
    }

     return new String(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
}'
```

Output I am getting is Compressed data:       �I-..)��K ��w�
BUT when I try to compress the same test string using any online gzip converter its giving me: eJwLSS0uUQguKcrMSwcAGKAEOA==

I am not sure why this difference is coming?

Comment: *BUT when I try to compress the same test string using any online gzip converter its giving me: eJwLSS0uUQguKcrMSwcAGKAEOA==* That's base64-encoded output. And you can't make a string out of binary (gzip) data like you're trying to do

Comment: You should use something like `return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());` You should get H4sIAAAAAAAA/wtJLS5RCC4pysxLBwCkn3eSCwAAAA==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing both binary with Base-64, and gzip with zlib.

First, compressed data makes use of all possible byte values, so it won't be printable. You also can't convert it to a string using `String` without losing information. Many channels can't handle all possible byte values, so in those cases, the compressed data is then *expanded* some to encode it to use only printable characters. The most common is [Base64 encoding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html), which is the example you are showing.

Second, that particular example, `eJwLSS0uUQguKcrMSwcAGKAEOA==`, is a Base64 encoding of a *zlib* stream, not a gzip stream. If you need a gzip stream, you generated that using the wrong tool. A Base64 gzip stream is immediately recognizable, as it will start with `H4sI`. For your test string, gzip compressed and Base64 encoded, you should get something like:

```
H4sIAJGKPWQAAwtJLS5RCC4pysxLBwCkn3eSCwAAAA==
```